# Set-AzureRMVMAccessExtension for Linux

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to programmatically change a Linux VM password in Azure.  The documentation for Set-AzureRMVMAccessExtension leads me to think this would work, however it hangs endlessly.

```
Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Credential (Get-Credential) -VMName $vm.Name -Name 'test' -Location $vm.Location
```

This starts executing and in the Azure VM extension blade for that VM I can see that 'test' was created but it is in an 'Unavailable' status.  Am I missing a parameter or a previous step?

If it matters, the Linux VM is the latest RHEL.

Comment: Can you mind using other command line to change password? Or you only want to use powershell cmdlet?

Comment: I suppose I could create two scripts, one for Linux VMs that use CLI and one for Windows that uses PoSH.  Not ideal but it would appear that is the route I have to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems related the **OS** of the VM. If I use the **Windows Server 2016 VM**, I run the command below.

```
$vmName = 'vmName '
$resourceGroupName = 'resourceGroupName '
$vm = Get-AzureRmVm -Name $vmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$credential = Get-Credential
Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Credential $credential -VMName $vm.Name -Name 'test' -Location $vm.Location
```

It adds an **Extension** whose `STATUS` is `Unavailable` at first, then I restart the VM in the portal, it works fine. Also, if we use  `$vm | Restart-AzureRmVM`, I think we will get the same result.

[image]

If I use the **latest RHEL Linux VM**, the command will run endlessly, but I can see the Extension has been created with a status of **Unavailable** in the portal. But after restarting the VM, the extension was missing.

According to this [article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/12/13/azure-vm-password-with-powershell.aspx), it seems the `Set-AzureRMVMAccessExtension` is for `windows`.

> Azure VMs generally have a small piece of software installed on them called a VM agent. This small agent is installed on the underlying **Windows OS** and communicates with Azure to allow the user control over the OS without necessarily touching the OS itself.

If it is possible, I recommend you to use **Azure CLI** to access it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-user-update).

Comment: Joy, I marked it as an answer, however; being new to SO I don't have the required reputation to make it appear publicly.  Thank you!

Comment: user error, you should see it appropriately marked now